# Auto Nested Tree Auto Expand not working in IE11 but is working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a nested tree which is an html table with buttons on each elements to get the child table via AJAX.  This works when done manually in IE and in chrome but I have a link to "Expand All" which selects all down arrow images on the page and .click()'s them. This happens on a 600 millisecond loop until all images are clicked and tables are opened. Here is the code for the auto click loop.

```
function autoClick(searchElement, clickElement) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($(searchElement).length > 0) {
            $(searchElement).each(function () {
                $(this).click();
            });
            $(clickElement).click();
        }
    }, 600);
    return ($(searchElement).length);
}
```

It doesn't even to click the first levels of the tree because when I watch for the ajax calls on the network monitor, none are fired. Here is the expand and collapse functions which utilize the autoclick loop.

```
function expandClick() {
if (!collapseExecuting) {
    expandExecuting = true;
    numOfExpandElements = autoClick('img[src="../Images/details_open.png"]', '#expandLink');
    if (numOfExpandElements == 0) {
        expandExecuting = false;
    }
}
}

function collapseClick() {
if (!expandExecuting) {
    collapseExecuting = true;
    numOfCollapseElements = autoClick('img[src="../Images/details_close.png"]', '#collapseLink');
    if (numOfCollapseElements == 0) {
        collapseExecuting = false;
    }
}
}
```

Here's the Click event handler:

```
$('#requestsTable tbody td img[data-description="toggle"]').live('click', function () { //alt="expand/collapse"
   // var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var parentid = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    var item = this;

    if (parentid == "requestsTable") {
        getChild("request", requestTable, item, "RequestCustomers?RequestID=" + $(this).data("request"));
    }
    else if (parentid == "customerTable") {
        getChild("customer", requestTable, item, ".." + $(this).data('url') + "?RequestID=" + $(this).data("customer"));
    }
    else if (parentid == "accountTable") {
        getChild("account", requestTable, item, ".." + $(this).data('url') + "?AccountNum=" + $(this).data("account") + "&RequestID=" + $(this).data("request"));
    }
});
```

If you need to see get child here it is too:

```
function getChild(details, rTable, item, getCall) {
var row = item.parentNode.parentNode;
var parentid = item.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
var rowClass = 'accountDetails';
if (item.src.match('details_close')) {
    /* This row is already open - close it */
    item.src = "../Images/details_open.png";
    $(item).attr('title', 'Expand');
    rTable.fnClose(row);
}
else {
    /* Open this row */
    item.src = "../Images/details_close.png";
    $(item).attr('title', 'Collapse');
    //set the class of the row based on the model being returned.
    if (details == 'request') {
        rowClass = 'requestDetails';
    } else if(details == 'customer') {
        rowClass = 'customerDetails';
    }
    $.get(getCall, function (response) {
        rTable.fnOpen(row, response, rowClass);
        if (response.BatchComplete) {
            $('#batchStatus').value('Batch Completed. <a href="/apps/SsaBatchReview/">Click here to send batch</a>.');
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the click event code?

Comment: I edited to add the click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was happening.  In my *ExpandClick* and *CollapseClick* functions I was selecting the elements via relative URLs in the SRC attribute.  Apparently in IE (at least IE 11) these relative URLs are mapped and then displayed in the source as absolute URLs.  In chrome it keeps the relative URLs as is in the source so my selector was able to target in Chrome but not IE.

Changed my selectors that I pass to the *autoClick* function and it worked:

```
function expandClick() {
    if (!collapseExecuting) {
        expandExecuting = true;
        numOfExpandElements = autoClick('img[title="Expand"]', '#expandLink');
        if (numOfExpandElements == 0) {
            expandExecuting = false;
        }
    }
}

function collapseClick() {
    if (!expandExecuting) {
        collapseExecuting = true;
        numOfCollapseElements = autoClick('img[title="Collapse"]', '#collapseLink');
        if (numOfCollapseElements == 0) {
            collapseExecuting = false;
        }
    }
}
```